# File piping with find

Tags: piping

When I run the command `cd dir && find . -name "*.html"`it perfectly displays all the html files including the html files in the sub-directories. But when I run the command `cd dir && find . -name "*.html" | for f in *.html; do "action"; done` only loops for me in the current directory but does no change to the html files in the sub-directories.  I tried incorporating the find in the for loop but only resulted in an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite it as

```
cd dir && find . -name "*.html" | while read f; do "action"; done
```

when you did

```
... for f in *.html; ...
```

you where in fact listing the html files in the current directory, it is equivalent to `ls *.html` in fact, and not filtering the list received form the pipe (which is being ignored)